# Split the graphql resolvers file into seperatefiles

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm working with GraphQL and have a **resolvers.js** file that looks like this:

```
const User = require("../models/User");
const Post = require("../models/Post");

module.exports = {
  Query: {
    async users(){...},
    async user(){...},
    async posts(){...},
    async post(){...},
  },
  User: {...},
  Post: {...},
  Mutation: {
    createUser(){...},
    login(){...},
    createPost(){...},
  },
}
```

But if I have more models, queries and mutations the file is gonna be very long. How can I split this into seperate files? One for user queries and mutations, one for posts and so. Or is that not possible? Maybe there's a way to combine this with the **schema.js** file? So that I can split the schema too and put schema/resolver from User into a file. I'm still a beginner in coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to do it very easy actually. In the schema.js I can use lodash merge to combine multiple resolver files and for the typedefs I just use an array. This way I can split everything into seperate files.

```
const { merge } = require("lodash");

module.exports = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: [typeDefs, userTypeDefs],
  resolvers: merge(resolvers, userResolvers)
});
```

Comment: https://blog.apollographql.com/modularizing-your-graphql-schema-code-d7f71d5ed5f2 supplies this solution if anyone wants more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody is looking for an answer in 2020,

I had the similar issue,
and I tried to adapt the method mentioned,
but found an easier way to solve the problem.

I used `graphql-tools`'s `mergeResolvers` to solve the issue - https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/merge-resolvers/

Example code would be like this

```
const { mergeResolvers } = require('@graphql-tools/merge');
const clientResolver = require('./clientResolver');
const productResolver = require('./productResolver');

const resolvers = [
  clientResolver,
  productResolver,
];

module.exports mergeResolvers(resolvers);
```

The `lodash` `merge` would not differentiate `Query` and `Mutation`,
thus throwing an error in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. Do note that this is in Typescript.

You would define your resolvers in separate files, such as this:

```
import { DateBidListResolvers } from "../../types/generated";

export const DateBidList: DateBidListResolvers.Type = {
  ...DateBidListResolvers.defaultResolvers,

  list: (_, __) => { // This is an example resolver of Type DateBidList
    throw new Error("Resolver not implemented");
  }
};
```

Then you would aggregate them together in a single file like this:

```
import { Resolvers } from "../../types/generated";

import { Query } from "./Query";
import { User } from "./User";
import { DateBid } from "./DateBid";
import { DateItem } from "./DateItem";
import { Match } from "./Match";
import { Mutation } from "./Mutation";
import { Subscription } from "./Subscription";
import { DateBidList } from "./DateBidList";
import { DateList } from "./DateList";
import { Following } from "./Following";
import { MatchList } from "./MatchList";
import { Message } from "./Message";
import { MessageItem } from "./MessageItem";
import { Queue } from "./Queue";

export const resolvers: Resolvers = {
  DateBid,
  DateBidList,
  DateItem,
  DateList,
  Following,
  Match,
  MatchList,
  Message,
  MessageItem,
  Mutation,
  Query,
  Queue,
  Subscription,
  User
};
```

You could then import that resolvers export into your configuration setup:

```
import { resolvers } from './resolvers/index';

// ... other imports here

export const server = {
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground,
  context,
  dataSources,
};

export default new ApolloServer(server);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Never worked with Typescript. Will take a look at how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need Typescript to do this. It was just to note on some of the lingo in the code. I would appreciate it if you would select my answer rather than yours so I get the points.